# Apply CSS to ionic 2 tabs and navbar

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, ionic2

I have build an ionic 2 app from scratch using Blank Template and i used TabsPage to be the rootPage for the app. Now i want to change the font-size and font-weight to the text display in  where i used tabTitle attribute to display the title for each tab so i try by setup basic css in .ts file like this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NewsPage } from '../news/news';
import { AboutusPage } from '../aboutus/aboutus';
import { ContactusPage } from '../contactus/contactus';

@Component ({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  template:`
    <ion-tabs color="background-blue">
      <ion-tab [root]="newsPage" tabTitle="الأخبار"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="aboutusPage" tabTitle="عن البرنامج"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="contactusPage" tabTitle="أتصل بنا"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  `,
  styles:[`
    page-tabs {
      .ios, .md {
            ion-tabs {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        }
    }
  `]
})

export class TabsPage {
  newsPage = NewsPage;
  aboutusPage = AboutusPage;
  contactusPage = ContactusPage;
}
```

The same this i want to apply those styles into navbar which display in NewsPage This is the code for this page Also you have to know that i apply some css using sass file:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the NewsPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-news',
  templateUrl: 'news.html',
})
export class NewsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NewsPage');
  }

}
```

```css
.ios, .md {
    page-news {
        ion-content {
            background-color: #f6f6f9;

            ion-card {
                ion-card-content {
                    padding-top: 0px;

                    ion-card-title {
                        font-size: 18px;
                    }
                    p {
                        font-size: 15px;
                    }
                }
                ion-item {
                    h2 {
                        font-size: 15px;
                    }
                    p {
                        font-size: 14px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color='background-blue'>
    <ion-title>الأخبار</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="../../assets/avatars/arwa.png" />
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2><b>ثانوية عروة بن الزبير</b></h2>
          <p>منطقة الجهراء التعليمية </p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col center text-left padding>
      <ion-note  dir="ltr" lang="en">
        1m
      </ion-note>
      <ion-note></ion-note>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        نجل زيدان لنضم لـ آلافيس
      </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        تعاقد نادي آلافيس الإسباني مع اللاعب الشاب إنزو زيدان من ريال مدريد لثلاثة مواسم مقبلة مع احتفاظ النادي الملكي بحق إعادة الشراء.
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <img src="http://s2.alraimedia.com/CMS/Attachments/2017/6/30/611246_2_-_Qu65_RT728x0-_OS990x557-_RD728x409-.jpg">
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="../../assets/avatars/alghanim.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2><b>ثانوية عبداللطيف ثنيان الغانم</b></h2>
      <p>منطقة الفروانية التعليمية </p>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col center text-left padding>
      <ion-note dir="ltr" lang="en">
        17 Jan 5
      </ion-note>
      <ion-note></ion-note>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        ألمانيا تسحق المكسيك
      </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        وضع المنتخب الألماني حدًا لمغامرة نظيره المكسيكي في بطولة كأس القارات، وحصد فوزًا مستحقًا بنتيجة 4-1، مساء اليوم الخميس، في نصف نهائي البطولة التي تستضيفها روسيا، ليضرب موعدًا مع تشيلي في النهائي.
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <img src="http://img.kooora.com/?i=reuters%2f2017-06-29%2f2017-06-29t181145z_254853844_rc12d4ad5380_rtrmadp_3_soccer-confederations-ger-mex_reuters.jpg">
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first style for page-tabs is wrong.

You are not adding the tabTitle selector or ion-tab tag.
And you should create a tabs.scss inside your tabs folder and delete the [styles] from your tabs.ts

Try adding this code inside tabs.scss:

```
.tab-button span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

So overall your tabs.scss will look something like this:

```
page-tabs {
  .ios, .md {
        ion-tabs {
             a.tab-button span {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your tabs.ts should look like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NewsPage } from '../news/news';
import { AboutusPage } from '../aboutus/aboutus';
import { ContactusPage } from '../contactus/contactus';

@Component ({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  template:`
    <ion-tabs color="background-blue">
      <ion-tab [root]="newsPage" tabTitle="الأخبار"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="aboutusPage" tabTitle="عن البرنامج"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab [root]="contactusPage" tabTitle="أتصل بنا"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  `
})

export class TabsPage {
  newsPage = NewsPage;
  aboutusPage = AboutusPage;
  contactusPage = ContactusPage;
}
```

And, if I understand you correctly, you want the ion-navbar title to have the same font-size and font-weight as your tabTitle selector, then:

You should modify your sass file, and add the style for the navbar. 
Should look like this:

```
.ios, .md {
    /* We add the code here */
    ion-header {
        ion-navbar {
            ion-title .toolbar-title {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        }
    }
    page-news {
        ion-content {
            background-color: #f6f6f9;

            ion-card {
                ion-card-content {
                    padding-top: 0px;

                    ion-card-title {
                        font-size: 18px;
                    }
                    p {
                        font-size: 15px;
                    }
                }
                ion-item {
                    h2 {
                        font-size: 15px;
                    }
                    p {
                        font-size: 14px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to add my own custom style to the tab title in tabs page right now the css i write don't have any effect in the app at all.

Comment: Still the css styles not applied and i have to say that i already know how to use overriding-ionic-variables to change font size but i want to know how i do it through css/sass file which make it easier for me.

Comment: @FahadAlDaferi Ok, I edited the code, try again if it works.
Just use .tab-button instead [tabTitle] or ion-tab. And for the navbar use .toolbar-title, It should work fine (In my end it works perfectly)

Comment: @Sebastain Thanks for navbar work fine but for tabs still no effect ?!

Comment: Weird. Try with /deep/ .tab-button { and tell me. If it still not works send me all your actual code of your page-tabs file

Comment: Still no effect i think the problem that the styles not take any effect on the page because i create TabsPage manually and not sure if i don't it right or wrong so you can download the full project from here goo.gl/FFohgY  and make sure to do npm install first before ionic serve

Comment: @FahadAlDaferi Ohhh I have seen your code. I think the problem is, that ionic2 don't support style encapsulation, I edited my answer again, you should create a tabs.scss and add the styles there, and delete the [styles] part from the tabs component. Let me know if that helps. PD: You should use [GitHub](http://www.github.com)  and upload your projects there, so anybody can see them and help you if you need it.

Comment: @Sebastain Thanks, Still no effect :)

Comment: I have make a lot of research into i get it done and you have to apply the style into the tab it self which NewsPage and change the style a little

Comment: `ion-tabs {
    a.tab-button {
      span {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: I'm glad that works for you :). Remember to try and have separete files for your code, and try to use Github. You can check my profile here if you need more help. https://github.com/SebastianGiro

Remember to close this question selecting que best answer, adding one yourself, editing your question, etc. So it will help more people in the future. Also, read this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles . Its very important to understand how to fix something in an easy and clean way (for css).

Answer (score 1):

Just copy & paste this css:

**For unselected tab:**

```
.tabs-md-primary .tab-button, .tabs-md-primary .tab-button-icon {
    color: black;
}
```

**For selected tab:**

```
.tabs-ios-primary .tab-button[aria-selected=true], .tabs-ios-primary .tab-button[aria-selected=true],
.tabs-md-primary .tab-button[aria-selected=true], .tabs-md-primary .tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top: white solid;
}
```

**[Click here to see tabs after adding above style in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QImwQ.png)**

Comment: Thanks for the help but still the code did not take any effect on tabs title not sure why ? even when i create a new tabs.scss file to host styles not work Is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: You have to know that i create TabsPage manually and register it to be rootPage in app.component.ts Also in app.module.ts declarations & entryComponents

Comment: I have to thank you too for give me the note about selected and unselected tab which solve my next move in advance :)